# File-system based queue in python

Tags: python, file-system, queue

I would like to implement a concurrent (multi-thread, multi-process) queue that is backed by file system. Data is pickled over a file, stored in a directory and given a sequential name.

The sequential name is milliseconds since epoch plus a random number that should prevent clashes. The queue will actually serve few processes and do few operations per second, but I wanted to be more general.

Also, this is thought to work on Linux, and I assumed that the rename of a file is atomic (I am not sure if it is the same on other platforms).
Therefore, I implemented a simple lock mechanism: `*.lock` files are ignored when popping from the queue, so a file will be locked (.lock suffix added) when being written and locked also when being read, then unlinked.

I think the only major flaw here is that collisions might occur when many threads or processes are being used, which won't happen in my case, but getting reviews from other eyes is definitely going to help.

```
import os
import time
import pickle
import random

from pathlib import Path


class FSQueue:
    def __init__(self, root, fs_wait=0.1, fifo=True):
        """Creates a FSQueue that will store data as pickle files in root."""
        self._root = Path(root)
        self._root.mkdir(exist_ok=True, parents=True)
        self._wait = fs_wait
        self._fifo = fifo

    def put(self, data):
        """Adds data to the queue by dumping it to a pickle file."""
        now = int(time.time() * 10000)
        rnd = random.randrange(1000)
        seq = f'{now:016}-{rnd:04}'
        target = self._root / seq
        fn = target.with_suffix('.lock')
        pickle.dump(data, fn.open('wb'))  # Write to locked file
        fn.rename(target)  # Atomically unlock

    def get(self):
        """Pops data from the queue, unpickling it from the first file."""
        # Get files in folder and reverse sort them
        while True:
            _, _, files = next(os.walk(self._root))
            files = sorted(files, reverse=not self._fifo)
            for f in files:
                if f.endswith('lock'):
                    continue  # Someone is writing or reading the file
                try:
                    fn = self._root / f
                    target = fn.with_suffix('.lock')
                    fn.rename(target)
                    data = pickle.load(target.open('rb'))
                    target.unlink()
                    return data
                except FileNotFoundError:
                    pass  # The file was locked by another get()
            # No files to read, wait a little bit
            time.sleep(self._wait)

    def qsize(self):
        """Returns the approximate size of the queue."""
        _, _, files = next(os.walk(self._root))
        n = 0
        for f in files:
            if f.endswith('lock'):
                continue  # Someone is reading the file
            n += 1
        return n

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = FSQueue('/tmp/test_queue')
    for i in range(10):
        q.put(f'data {i}')
    assert q.qsize() == 10
    for i in range(11):
        print(q.get())  # The last one should wait
```

Comment: Ok, to make the file creation a bit more robust, I am now using `x` for file creation instead of `w`, inside a loop with a try-except block.